# Can not Use Async Class inside an Activity . The Activity already Consist of a Main class extending from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

```
public class Server_Activity extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {


}
```

An error is shown when I write this class:

> ClassServer_Activity must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method doInBackground(params).

What is causing this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the method `doInBackground()`. This is because the AsyncTask is an abstract class, which also contains the abstract method `doInBackground()`. This means, that any class inheriting from the AsyncTask class must also implement the `doInBackground()` method.

But your title seems to be another question, sounding like you wrote your `Server_Activity` class in the same file of another activity. in Eclipse this error would sound like:

> The public type Testclass must be defined in its own file

If this is the case: Create a new `.java` file and write there your `Server_Activity` class.
And don't forget to implement the `doInBackground()` method there.

You can see an example of this in the [android developer api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#Usage).

Answer (score 0):

implements doInBackground method in your code. Press ctrl+i, choose doInBackground and then enter to make it easy

Comment: yes...i tried it and it returns me an error  . " class server activity is public , should be declared in a file server_acivity.java. how can i resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

based on the documentation you have to implement doInBackground. as doInbackground method is declared as abstract.
see documentations 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> protected abstract Result doInBackground (Params... params)
>
> Added in API level 3 Override this method to perform a computation on
>   a background thread. The specified parameters are the parameters
>   passed to execute(Params...) by the caller of this task. This method
>   can call publishProgress(Progress...) to publish updates on the UI
>   thread.
>
> Parameters params The parameters of the task. Returns A result,
>   defined by the subclass of this task.

in your case Params... params is Void

> ↳  android.os.AsyncTask